# Only keep unique values in setdefaults dict

Tags: python, collections

I'm making two tables/dicts using the setdefault() function from collections module. The first dict is created from two lists that are zipped where the first item element becomes the key and the the second elements become the values so that there can be any number of values per key. Is there a way to exclude duplicate values for each key?

```
keylst = ['a','a','b','b','a','b']
vallst = [1,1,2,2,3,3]

zip = [('a',1),('a',1),('b',2),('b',2),('a',3),('b',3)]
result = a[1,1,3], b[2,2,3]

desired_result = a[1,3], b[2,3]
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import collections
import xlrd

#open workbook to get values
wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(r"S:\Bands.xlsx")
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

#Open a rate code workbook
wb2 = xlrd.open_workbook(r"S:\Sands.xlsx")
sh2 = wb2.sheet_by_index(0)

#make a lists

roLst = []
raLst = []

# polpulate lists

cell_range_value = 0
for value in sh1.col(9):
    cell_range_value += 1
print cell_range_value

for i in range(1,cell_range_value,1):
    roVal = str(sh1.cell(i,9).value)
    raVal = str(sh1.cell(i,19).value)
    cell_value_id = sh1.cell(i,1).value
    roLst.append(roVal)
    raLst.append(raVal)

#make multivalue dict1
RoRaDct = {}

for key, item in zip(roLst,raLst):
    RoRaDct.setdefault(key,[]).append(item)

for key, item in RoRaDct.items():
    print key, item

#make multivalue dict2

fType = []
rtLst2 = []

cell_range_value = 0
for value in sh2.col(0):
    cell_range_value += 1

for i in range(1,cell_range_value,1):
    fVal = str(sh2.cell(i,1).value)
    rtVal = str(sh2.cell(i,0).value)
    cell_value_id = sh2.cell(i,1).value
    fType.append(fVal)
    rtLst2.append(rtVal)

TpRtDct = {}

#check values

for key, item in zip(fType,rtLst2):
    TpRtDct.setdefault(key,[]).append(item)

for key, item in TpRtDct.items():
    print key, item
```

Comment: Do you need `list` values or can you make your code work with `set` instead?

Comment: A set would be fine. I suppose I can loop through the dicts after they're created and make their values a set.

Comment: Yep. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, you can change the `setdefault` to

```
TpRtDct.setdefault(key,set()).add(item)
```

Also, keep in mind that after the addition of `defaultdict` it is considered more readable to write

```
RoRaDct = defaultdict(set)

for key, item in zip(roLst,raLst):
    RoRaDct[key].add(item)
```

Comment: I just looped through the dict after it's creation like so: for key, item in RoRaDct.items():
    item = set(item). Is defaultdict() more efficient?

Comment: Print again after that. This wont change the items in the dictionary. You are iterating over a copy.

Comment: I don't think defaultdict is more efficient, just more readable, and it is the suggested way

Comment: You're right. When I print the dict after the values are no longer unique.

Comment: @blue_note -- `defaultdict` will (probably) be more efficient.  With `setdefault`, you're basically creating a new `set` each time `setdefault` is called.  With `defaultdict`, you only call `set` when there isn't already a `set` there.  How much more efficient probably depends on a lot of factors though -- much of the time the efficiency difference will probably be negligible.

Comment: Thanks blue_note and mgilson. I ended up using defaultdict. Works great!

Comment: @mgilson: Obviously you are right about that, I thought the question was whether defaultdict is more efficient than the .setdefault() approach (the phrasing of the question could mean either). Either way, good note, thans

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it would be nice if you could create a dictionary of `OrderedSet` objects which would preserve the order *and* guarantee that only unique values where added to it at the same time.

Unfortunately Python doesn't have such a class built-in, but you can use an `OrderedDict` in its place. The advantage to using  a `set` (or `dict`) being that membership checks for uniqueness will be faster than if simple `list`s were used to collect the values.

Here's what I mean:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

keylst = ['a','a','b','b','a','b']
vallst = [1,1,2,2,3,3]

result = {}
for k,v in zip(keylst, vallst):
    result.setdefault(k, OrderedDict())[v] = 1

# convert final values in result dictionary into lists
for key, value in result.items():
    result[key] = list(value.keys())  # In Python 2.x, just use = values.keys()

print(result)  # -> {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

P.S. Here's an `OrderedSet` [recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) by Raymond Hettinger which you could use instead simulating one with an `OrderedDict` as done in the code above.